# What can I do when my Nikon D5200 gives an SD card error with every card?

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting, memory-card, sdcard

My D5200 has developed a problem, every time I turn it on I get the error message "This memory card cannot be used. Card may be damaged Insert another card." I have tried multiple memory cards in the camera and tested them on another camera to ensure that they work but the message still shows. I followed following instructions from Nikon but problem still remain.

> 1. Remove battery, Memory card, and lens for about 30 seconds
> 2. Reinsert just the lens and the battery, power the camera on
>      ensure you are using an approved card: Answer Title: Approved SD cards for D5200 Answer Link:https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18424
> 3. The camera settings can be restored to default values by holding the "Menu" and "i" buttons down together for more than two seconds
>
> (these buttons are marked by a green dot). The information display turns off briefly  while settings are reset.
>
> 4. Hit the menu button and select custom setting menu
> 5. Select "F" for controls and then "F4" labels " Slot empty release lock"
> 6. Highlight "Enable release"
> 7. Test camera with no card/ then reinsert the card and try again

After this I am able to take pictures in demo mode, but the SD card still gives error.

I bought this one and half years ago from the US. I am in Canada, and Nikon wants me to send it to USA and says it will cost 400+ bucks. This is just too much for me. Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Have you inspected the card slot for physical damage or anything blocking the contacts?

Comment: Look carefully in the narrow slot where the contacts are for the gold tabs of the card. If a card is inserted backwards and *forced*, those contacts can get bent over. It *might* be possible to bend them back with a fine bent probe, but more likely will require professional repair.

Comment: Format the card. Even on another camera but make sure its completely blank. I've seen this happen on a Nikon 1 J5 just last week. it didn't like that the card had some hidden files introduced by a Mac.

Comment: You will save a lot of money taking it to a local repair shop.  Especially since the body probably isn't worth much more than $400CAD...

Comment: Did you try format you SD card with another camera?

Comment: I have recently discovered my d5200 malfunctions with an error message and right now only gives me an error message about every 20 -30 photos. I then have to eject the card and insert again so it can work.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some suggestions as to how to approach your problem:

- *Clean out the contacts within the card slot, if dirty* — This can be done using compressed air, or very gentle work with pliers or q-tips with some cleaning alcohol based detergent
- *Try smaller and/or slower sd-cards* — sd-cards comes in different classes/sizes, your camera might have difficulties with the classes/sizes you've tried so far
- *Upgrade firmware of camera* — This is a long shot, but you could possibly have an issue with the firmware/software on your camera accessing the sd-cards, and thusly an upgrade could cure it
- *Reformat cards on a different platform* — If possible reformat one of the sd-cards using the camera (if possible), or a different camera, or on a different computer
- *Insert the card at another time* — You've most likely tried this already, but if you previously inserted card before turning on camera, try inserting it afterwards, or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Here is what I found fixed the problem:

Format using the correct SD card formatting tool, which can be downloaded from sdcard.org.

The windows formatting tool doesn't do the job correctly.

Ran this with just a quick format and it worked straight away.

Comment: The windows tool does the job just fine, you just have to make sure you choose the correct options.

Comment: A camera will do the formating job just fine, no need to tune the parameters.

Comment: @ManuH It is kind of difficult to format the card if the camera refuses to recognize the card...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a microSD card with adapter, try changing the adapter. This solution works for me. I've found  adapters from Adata and Kingstone to be corrupt.

Comment: Nothing in the question says that the poster is using an adapter.

Comment: Nothing in the questions says that the poster isn't using an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera is clearly broken since the same problem is exhibited with multiple cards.

Since repair from Nikon will be probably more than the camera is worth you should consider a local repairer.  You can find them online or if you visit a camera store they will either be able to do the work for you or be able to put you in touch with a reliable repairer who can do the work for significantly less than Nikon would charge.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Nikon D5500 I bought through eBay from USA over a year ago. I have used it for not more than 1000 pics, literally brand new. Tried multiple cards no luck. A local repairman here in New Zealand quoted NZ$400 to fix a faulty main board.

Try local repair guy. You’ll save alot.